# Python - ast - How to find first function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find the first function in arbitrary Python code.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
import ast
import compiler.ast

code = """\
def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2

"""

tree = compiler.parse(code)

print list(ast.walk(tree))
```

But I'm getting an error I don't understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print list(ast.walk(tree))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 215, in walk
    todo.extend(iter_child_nodes(node))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 180, in iter_child_nodes
    for name, field in iter_fields(node):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 168, in iter_fields
    for field in node._fields:
AttributeError: Module instance has no attribute '_fields'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ast.parse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse), not `compiler.parse`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> 
>>> code = """
... def func1():
...     return 1
... 
... def func2():
...     return 2
... """
>>> 
>>> tree = ast.parse(code)
>>> [x.name for x in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(x, ast.FunctionDef)]
['func1', 'func2']
```

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I'm still not seeing how I can get the names of the functions at this point.

Comment: Ok this seems to work `[v for v in ast.walk(tree) if type(v) == ast.FunctionDef][0]`

Answer (score 0):

What about this, please let me know if that works:

```
import ast
import compiler.ast

code = """\
def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2
"""

n = compiler.parse(code).getChildNodes()
print n[0].nodes[0].name
```

Comment: The question is to find the first function in **arbitrary** code, not the first **ast node**, that's the reason why I downvoted.